# Lisp merging pattern

Tags: list, merge, lisp

I am quite new in lisp, so maybe it is a stupid question. But I would like to merge two lists (s1, s2) according to a given pattern - list S3 of boolean (t nil....). If true use the element from S2, if false use the element as it is.  So the final should look like for 
s1 (1 2 3 2 2 4) and s2 (8 9 5 6 8 9) and S3 (nil t nil t t nil) => (1 8 3 9 5 4)

Thank you very much!
R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp is a family of languages. If you mean Common Lisp, here is a possible two-lines solution:

```
CL-USER> (defun merge-3 (s1 s2 s3)
           (loop for x in s1 if (pop s3) collect (pop s2) else collect x))
MERGE-3
CL-USER> (merge-3 '(1 2 3 2 2 4) '(8 9 5 6 8 9) '(nil t nil t t nil))
(1 8 3 9 5 4)
```